# Why both angle $\alpha$ is same

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

In above picture $R$ is radius of curvature $BE$ and $\alpha$ is angle between tangent to curvature $BE$ at point $E$ with vertical axis.

They have claimed that angle $POE$ is also $\alpha$ can you explain why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\angle OET$ is a right-angle, and therefore $\angle OEP=90^\circ-\alpha$, and $\angle OPE$ is also a right-angle.

Comment: I could not understand why angle $OEP$ is $90 - \alpha$, angle $TEY$ is $\alpha$ then they have claimed that $POE$ is also $\alpha$, i am asking how is that possible, thx for reply

Comment: @Nivekithan; fixed

Comment: thx understood, for some reason I forgot that angle $PEY$ is $180$